# SVG text elements piling on top of one another at the 0,0 position - D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, text

I created many SVG text elements for a map I'm making in D3.
They show up in my Document as grand-children to the Body and as children to an SVG container I created.

See here: [my DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy5mS.png)

However, every element piles on top of the other, stuck at the 0,0 position.
Interestingly, when the text elements are OUTSIDE of the body, they render fine.

Here's how I generated the elements using D3...

```js
var a=["", "Albany Park", "Archer Heights", "Armour Square", "Ashburn", "Auburn Gresham", "Austin", "Avalon Park", "Avondale", "Belmont Cragin", "Beverly", "Bridgeport", "Brighton Park", "Burnside", "Calumet Heights", "Chatham", "Chicago Lawn", "Clearing", "Douglas", "Dunning", "East Garfield Park", "East Side", "Edgewater", "Edison Park", "Englewood", "Forest Glen", "Fuller Park", "Gage Park"];

var canvas = d3.select("body") //select the body
            .append("svg") //append an svg container
            .attr("id", "drawingBoard") //give that container an id
            .attr("height", 600) //specify dimensions
            .attr("width", 600)

canvas.selectAll("#drawingBoard")
    .data(a)
    .enter() //make as many potential elements as there are data items
    .append("text") //make those potential elements real
    .style("font-family", "Calibri", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", ".6em")
    .html(function(x){return x+ "<br>"}); //Populates the new elements with text.
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>En Route to D3, SVG, and Javascript Mastery</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <script      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SVG **isn't** HTML.  Your text nodes require positioning via the `x` and `y` attributes or a `transform`.  Also they won't render HTML mark-up so those `<br>` tags are meaningless.  If you want HTML, just use HTML.

Comment: I know it's not HTML. Actually, the <br> tags did make a difference. Looking at my Document, when the text elements are rendered OUTSIDE the body, they show up on one line if the <br> tags aren't included. How would I do a transform? Got any other ideas? Here's a fiddle of it:: https://jsfiddle.net/kadenz/wf2h3hdm/

Comment: If you want to stack them, set a y position.  Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf2h3hdm/2/), the `i` is the index of the element in the data.

Comment: Wow, awesome. I don't completely understand why that works, but I'm beginning to wrap my head around it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I wrote my comments up as a proper answer, hopefully it helps you understand a little better.  Happy `d3`ing...

Comment: When they are outside the body d3 is creating HTML text elements and not SVG text elements. That's why `<br>` works and they don't pile up.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text nodes in svg do not position themselves as normal HTML DOM elements would.  Instead they [require explicit positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x) via the `x` and `y` attributes (or a transform). By not setting those attributes the browser sets them to their default of `0`.

So, how can we position them?  This is were the `d3` data-binding magic comes in handy.  Here I'm using the [attr](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr) method which takes a function callback as it's second argument.  To this function are passed the datum (your text) and the index of the element in the data array.  So it's then as simple as:

```
index * 15 -> 0, 15, 30, 45, etc...
```

This is a pixel position.  Below I'm also adding 10 so the first value in the array is not cut in half.

```js
var a=["Albany Park", "Archer Heights", "Armour Square", "Ashburn", "Auburn Gresham", "Austin", "Avalon Park", "Avondale", "Belmont Cragin", "Beverly", "Bridgeport", "Brighton Park", "Burnside", "Calumet Heights", "Chatham", "Chicago Lawn", "Clearing", "Douglas", "Dunning", "East Garfield Park", "East Side", "Edgewater", "Edison Park", "Englewood", "Forest Glen", "Fuller Park", "Gage Park"];

var canvas = d3.select("body") //select the body
            .append("svg") //append an svg container
            .attr("id", "drawingBoard") //give that container an id
            .attr("height", 600) //specify dimensions
            .attr("width", 600);

var g = canvas.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

g.selectAll('text').data(a)
    .enter() //make as many potential elements as there are data items
    .append("text") //make those potential elements real
    .style("font-family", "Calibri", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", ".6em")
    .text(function(x){return x}) //<-- use .text, .html is meaningless here since it's not html.  Also, no need for the <br>, it's svg so you'll just get that as text
    .attr('y', function(d,i){
      // set the x attribute
      return (i * 15);
    })
    .style('alignment-baseline', 'hanging');
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>En Route to D3, SVG, and Javascript Mastery</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <script      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, why does the first array position get cut off without the blank value or the + 10? Just looking for as much info, which will hopefully lead to understanding, as I can get ;-)

Comment: @kadenz, by default, the y pixel position is where to put the bottom baseline of the text.  [You can change this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline)  See the edits I made to my code snippet above for another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Two other questions...how would I group all of those text elements (so i can transform them)? And, how would I call the text from an external json file's attributes? Instead of .data(a), something like .data(data/place.json.features.properties.place_name)

Comment: @kadenz, first question, you would wrap the `text` nodes into a `g` (group) and then transform the `g`, see edits above.  Second question, you generally retrieve the JSON through an ajax call, then data-bind.  See [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json).